# RabbitMQ: вопрос оптимизации очередей

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, rabbitmq

Я новичок в RabbitMQ. Прочитал статью «[Deploying Microservices Architecture with C#, Part 2](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/Articles/2015/10/02/Microservices-Csharp-Part-2.aspx?Page=1#)».

После прочтения задался следующим вопросом. Есть ли какие-то оптимальные решения по определению количества очередей, если количество клиентов изначально неизвестно.

Дано ASP.NET MVC + RabbitMQ(Pub/Sub).

- Вариант 1: одна очередь для всех клиентов.
- Вариант 2: одна очередь на каждого клиента.
- Вариант 3: пул очередей.

Как определить количество очередей в таком пуле?

Answer (score 3):

Вообще практика зависит от конкретной задачи, но вариант с очередью для каждого пользователя - это точно не относиться к теме Rabbitmq и если вы используете это, то вы делаете что-то неправильно, очередь сообщений не создана для таких структур. Сообщений по сути всегда должно быть больше чем очередей.

Например, нам нужно обеспечить быструю и эффективную многопоточную обработку видео загружаемых пользователями. Для этого мы создаем очередь с названием video_processing и публикуем туда задачи по обработке.

1. Пользователь зашел на сайт и загрузил видео, отправилось сообщение в очередь.
2. Консьюмер увидел эту задачу и заблокировал ее на время выполнения
3. Консьюмер начал обрабатывать задачу
4. Консьюмер завершил выполнение задачи, куда-то записал отчет
5. Консьюмер удалил задачу из очереди, таким образом сказав что она завершена успешно
6. Пользователь получил свое конвертированное видео

В этом сценарии консьюмер мог упасть (сервер перезагрузился), и реббит легко бы отдал задачу другому консьюмеру на выполнение, и следовательно производительность вашей очереди зависит лишь от кол-ва воркеров, которые выполняют задачи из очереди. А также вы бы могли кинуть это сообщение в другую очередь и продолжить его обработку по другим алгоритмам.

Сервер очередей в основном используется для задач связанных с

1. Обработкой данных
2. Управлением процессами
3. Интеграцией и взаимодействием систем

**В основном делают одну очередь под определенную задачу (например, очередь отправки писем пользователям), как определить сколько вам очередей нужно, опять же зависит от вашей задачи.**

Comment: пример с видео понятен.
но как быть если нужно маленькое время отклика (например много пользователей ломятся за аутентификацией)

Comment: @Atlantis RabbitMq не подходит для таких задач и использовать очередь для таких задач нецелесообразно. Если нужно увеличить скорость отклика на авторизацию, надо оптимизировать базу, использовать кеширование, мастшабирование, можно вынести авторизационный сервис в микросервис и масштабировать только его и т.д.

Comment: Спасибо за такие исчерпывающие ответы! По поводу целесообразности использования "кролика" для такой задачи - сомнения начали закрадываться уже в середине статьи, но, поскольку, я только начинаю осваивать этот инструмент, подумал что где-то не хватает знаний (хотя на самом деле теории уже очень много изучил). Остался тогда только один вопрос: может быть есть какие-то материалы, из которых можно узнать когда выгодно использовать очереди, когда нет, или это только практический опыт подскажет? Еще раз спасибо заранее!

Comment: @Atlantis большая часть использования очередей это интеграция отдельных компонентов и отложенные задачи, вот тут неплохо описаны типичные сценарии https://www.insight-it.ru/erlang/2012/rabbitmq/